# Removing Stopwords from String

Tags: android, string, stop-words, removeall

I need to remove stopwords from a string. I use the following code to remove stopwords and setting the final output in a textView. But when i run the code it always give the output "bugs". In other words it always give me the last string word as output. Please Check my code and Help!

```
public class Testing extends Activity {
TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testing);
    t1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so" +
            " much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> stopWordsSet = new HashSet<String>();
    stopWordsSet.add("I");
    stopWordsSet.add("THIS");
    stopWordsSet.add("AND");
    stopWordsSet.add("THERE'S");

    for(String word : words)
    {
        String wordCompare = word.toUpperCase();
        if(!stopWordsSet.contains(wordCompare))
        {
            wordsList.add(word);
        }
    }

    for (String str : wordsList){
        System.out.print(str+" ");
        t1.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t1.setText(str);` means it doesn't care what the previous text was. It puts the last one in loop. So use [`append`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

```
t1.append(str);
```

OR Append every single `str` to a single String and set that in `TextView` after the loop.

Comment: @ArslanAli Great to hear.

Comment: Can you tell me what to do to give spaces in the final output
Iam getting the output i want but all the words are joined. They should be separated by spaces

Comment: @ArslanAli :D Where did you ?

Comment: Oh Iam sorry I voted 1 for this answer and i thought this is the acceptance , i forgot to tick also :(

Answer (score 1):

The output is "bugs." because of this line of code:

```
 t1.setText(str);
```

which will re-write the textview everytime inside the loop. Because the last iteration the word is "bugs.", the textview will display bugs.

If you want to append the string instead of re-writting it use:

```
 t1.append(str);
```

Hope it helps.